# HTML Div Width with Overflow: Auto?

Tags: css, html, width, scrollbar

I'm creating a `div` like the following:

#### Edit: Here's an example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; max-height: 15em;">
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
            <label><input type="checkbox"/>Hello! Hello!</label><br/>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The text of every label unnecessarily *wraps* to the next line.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it a viable option for you to just put a couple `&nbsp;` on the end of the div to force it the extra couple of characters?

Comment: @George: I actually tried that, but it doesn't work -- it always overflows the characters that would be in place of the scrollbar.

Comment: Your markup does not validate. It should look [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/vSLXk/).

Comment: @NGLN: Er... thanks, but that sort of beside the point. And yours doesn't do what I need: The **width** of your `div` is 100%, instead of being the same as that of the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Attempt 1**

Add to the `div`,

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

The problem with this was the vertical scrollbar that appears impedes on the content slightly introducing a small unnecessary horizontal scrollbar.

---

**Attempt 2**

Add to the `div`,

```
white-space: nowrap;
padding-right: 1.5em;   // increase as appropriate
```

The problem here is that you're guessing the size of the vertical scrollbar to remove the horizontal one.

---

**Attempt 3**

Add to the `div`,

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Now, the horizontal scrollbar is removed, and the size of the vertical one is not being guessed, *but* it is always visible.

---

**Attempt 4**

The problem seems to boil down to needing to reserve the space for a scrollbar, as `overflow-y: scroll;` does but without it always being visible. The first solution that came to mind was to add an extra `div` alongside the first that has `overflow-y: scroll;` set and a `width: 100%;`. The problem was that with a regular `div` the scrollbar is included in the width. After some trial and error though, it seems that if you use a `float` it isn't. So by using an extra `float` you can force the width of the container to be larger by a scrollbars width, and then setting `width: 100%;` on the original div, it will take up the extra space too. You hide the extra float by setting it's height to `0`.

N.B. I'm not entirely sure why this works myself, and I've only tested on Firefox5 where it seems to work. I hope it's helpful for you. So,

Add,

```
<div class="hack"></div>
```

below you're original `div`. Then,

```
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 15em;
}

.hack {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;   
    height: 0;
}
```

An edit of your [jsfiddle including this fix is here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ttb6/3/).

Comment: This is awesome! But now there's a small scrollbar on the bottom that scrolls for like 5 pixels. Any way to just make the thing bigger?

Comment: @Mehrdad. I still think I've missed the point. I thought it was a vertical scrollbar that was the problem. This method will still leave a horizontal one. I'll reread again and keep thinking.

Comment: No, the vertical scrollbar *is* the problem! But once I prevent whitespace wrapping, a horizontal one appears.

Comment: @max: Yes, I *want* it to be there, but it's the *cause* of the wrapping problem. I want it to be there, but to **make the box bigger when it appears**, so that it doesn't take up text room.

Comment: @Mehrdad. Do you mean that you get a small horizontal scrollbar even if the content has not overrun? I can't reproduce this in Firefox5. What browser are you using and does changing to `overflow: scroll;` help? I'll tell you what, can you give us a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: Ugh, explaining this seems to be harder than I thought... let me think of a better way of explaining it... (If I can reproduce this in jsfiddle, sure. I'm using Chrome right now.)

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJc9k/1/) that should show the problem. (Notice the unnecessary wrapping, caused by the scrollbar.)

Comment: @Mehrdad. Got it, and have a (slightly hacky) solution by adding padding, check my update.

Comment: Yeah but... what if it's more than 1.5em? (e.g. particularly wide scrollbar) That's kind of the issue here... there *must* be a way to do this without being hacky. :\ (+1 for the help, anyhow)

Comment: @Mehrdad. OK, think we've got there. Check my update. You may want to add some padding too.

Comment: Yeah, but now the scrollbar is *always* visible. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad Well, this has been driving me nuts ever since you asked it! I was sure there had to be another way. You've probably already decided what you're going to use by now, but I've come up with a new solution. See my update (Attempt 4). You may well consider it even more hacky than the others. But if it works at all(!) I think it will work for scrollbars of unknown widths. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Haha this is a little overkill, but I do appreciate the help. :) I just decided to use the 1.5em thing, praying it works. Thanks for taking the time to answer this! :)

Answer (score 1):

From what i see, you need just the vertical scroll bar. This should should do the trick.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce a vertical scrollbar with `overflow-y: scroll;`.

**Edit:**

Oké, finally I think it's clear what you want.

See this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/vSLXk/2/).

CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 15em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <label for="check">Some text.</label>
</div>
```

**Edit 2:**

Ok, maybe [this is what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/VJc9k/8/)? I hope you don't mind the extra padding if there are just a few lines in the div.

Comment: Yes, but my text still wraps that way. I need the width to auto-size to the text.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/VJc9k/) to see what I mean... it doesn't seem to work that way either.

Comment: @Mehrdad Pffiew. Ok, updated again... ;-) I hope you don't mind the padding in the case there are just a few lines.

Comment: I don't mind the padding *itself*, but I *do* mind the fact that you're *assuming* that a scrollbar has a certain width. That's hacky... :\

Comment: @Mehrdad Agreed, but see no other way. Just pick the widest from all browsers (there likely is some limit). The alternative seems to enforce the scrollbar always.

Comment: @Mehrdad Or you could probably use javascript. Is that an option?

Comment: @tjm: That's overkill. :P I think I'll just go with the extra padding, but I really hate doing that...